# JavaScript getSelection issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
if (!window.x) {
  x = {};
}

x.Selector = {};

x.Selector.getSelected = function() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    t = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.getSelection) {
    t = document.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return t;
}

function htmlSpanHlt() {
  element = document.createElement("span");
  element.setAttribute('class', 'hlt');
  return element;
}

function highlight_text(sel) {
  span = htmlSpanHlt();
  if (sel.getRangeAt) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  }
  span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
  range.insertNode(span);
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu ius autem labitur complectitur, eos aliquip nostrud ei, ludus erroribus vel ex. Sea ex erat quaeque intellegam, et diam iusto deterruisset sea. Summo minimum periculis pro ea, diam soleat id pro. Cu putent inimicus eum,
    hinc comprehensam ex qui. Delectus appetere interesset ad mel.
    <br>
    <br>Ius ut quis summo utroque, in sea numquam percipit eloquentiam. Vidit mucius iudicabit ius id. Id mel vero dolorem. Sale lorem tempor ius ex, commodo reprehendunt pro cu. Mel ea accumsan mentitum liberavisse, labores fabellas per te.
  </p>
</div>
```

When I highlight the text normally like dragging the mouse everything will be fine. The issue is: Example when I double click the text many times or even once, of course everything will be selected but some text that are already highlighted will be back to normal. Can u help me to fix this issue? thanks a lot.

Comment: It should just work as expected; what happens? I can't see the issue from what you've currently given. It's good you included the code, but would you be able to put it into a working example using jsfiddle or similar? This would help us see what's going wrong.

Comment: if u really understand the code if u know how to code u would trace it. Somehow this is an issue. it is not normal when double click the text then some back to normal. i understand your side thanks anyway.

Comment: "Somehow this is an issue." But what is the issue? Either: you double-click, which highlights some text, but some text that _should_ be highlighted isn't highlighted, and _that's_ the issue. Or: you double-click, highlights some text, code doesn't capture all the highlighted text correctly, making it _seem_ like some of the text is actually not highlighted. Or: double-click, highlights some text, some text isn't highlighted (expected for whatever reason) but in those cases, your code messes up in some way. It would help to have more specifics, or a working example to _see_ what the problem is.

Comment: sorry about that Sir. maybe your are. i just only need more idea to do this. not specifically that someone can make a code for me. thank u for ur help sir maybe i will fix it on my own. have a great day.

Comment: Sorry if I seemed snooty. I just have no idea what the problem is. Each of the possible problems I listed would have drastically different solutions, and drastically different ways of debugging to _find_ the solutions. I was only asking so I could help you better. I guess I'll just give you a load of guesses and hope one of them is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Things to think about:

[Range.extractContents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/extractContents) may not be the function you want to use. It *removes* the content from the page and puts it in a temporary DocumentFragment (in memory, not in the page at all).

...Though it looks like this might be intentional, in the `highlight_text()` function. Without any context, I can't be sure.

Running that code snippet doesn't seem to mess up any highlighting in browser, whether clicking and dragging, or double-clicking or otherwise. On the first click, the currently highlighted text will unhighlight--maybe that's what you mean?

Comment: It's quite hard to get very close to anything useful without first understanding the issue you're trying to solve. But here are some things that may or may not be useful. Not really an "answer," but maybe this will help anyway.

Comment: highlight_text() function yes that is. yes maybe Range extractContents is the wrong method for this, but that is my only way to override highlights so far.

Comment: If it's just to style the highlights, you can use CSS to do some things like that. If it's to just get a reference to the text to be able to show a popup or manipulate the text, things like that, then you could just use the reference instead of removing it and adding it back in. What are you trying to do with overriding the highlights? Maybe I can be of more help.